# Finding the profile _id of person with maximum number of booking

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below. I wanted to find the profile_id with maximum number of Book_ids.

```
PROFILE_ID    BOOK_ID
---------- --------------------
A1         001
A2         002
A3         003
A1         004
A3         005
A1         006
A4         007
A1         008
A2         009
A4         010
A3         011
```

So, first i need to count how many bookings are done by distinct profile_id and I did it like below

```
SQL>select profile_id, count(book_id) from book group by pro;

PROFILE_ID       COUNT(BOOK_ID)
---------- --------------
A4                      2
A3                      3
A1                      4
A2                      2
```

but i wanted the query to return the profile_id with maximum count of booking. And for that, I used the below query

```
select profile_id from(select profile_id, count(book_id) no_of from book group by pro) deriv where deriv.no_of=max(deriv.no_of);
```

But it doesn't return the profile_id with max count of booking. I tried many different queries but it won't work.
Can anyone please help me. I am trying to write a general query but not for this particular table.
Little help would me a lot. Thank you

Comment: if you want to find the profle_id having the maximum number of bookings, what is the maximum number of booking? is it like when the number of books exceed like 10 bookings then it should only show the list of profile_id that exceeded 10 bookings?

Comment: i just wanted the maximum booking made by a profile_id. If you see the second table with column profile_id and count(book_id), you should notice that profile_id as "A1" has maximum count of booking_id. I just wanted to write the query to get return "A1". I hope you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, i think you need the order by

```
select profile_id, count(book_id) as no_of 
from book 
group by pro
order by no_of desc
limit 1
```

Update to when you need more than 1 results:

```
SELECT profile_id,
       count(book_id) AS no_of
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY profile_id
HAVING no_of =
  (SELECT max(no_of)
   FROM
     (SELECT profile_id,
             count(book_id) AS no_of
      FROM tbl1
      GROUP BY profile_id) tblAlias1)
```

Comment: I can't use limit because if I have two or more profile_ids with maximum count of book_id, I wont get all the profile_ids with max no.of book_ids  instead I get one 1 or 2 according to what I give as limit.

Comment: @ManoBhargav ok you can try my updated sql above

Comment: it tried your query, but it is giving an error like below,
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NO_OF": invalid identifier

Comment: thanks for your effort in helping me. I got the correct query. I mentioned it below. Thanks again.
SQL>  Select pro from book group by pro having count(book_id)>=all(select count(book_id) from book group by pro);

Comment: @ManoBhargav . . . You can't use `limit` because Oracle doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use `fetch first`:

```
select profile_id, count(*)
from book 
group by profile_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want all profiles when there are duplicates, then one method is:

```
select profile_id, count(*)
from book 
group by profile_id
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only with ties;
```

Oracle has supported `fetch first` since version 12C.

In older versions, you would use window functions:

```
select profile_id, cnt
from (select profile_id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from book b
      group by profile_id
     ) b
where seqnum = 1;
```